# neo4j cypher to filter multi paths based on two relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph:

[image]

I need to get all the AD nodes which are related to a particular User node. If I search by a user B1, I should get all the AD nodes which are connected by HAS relation to B1 node as well as the AD nodes which are connected to its parent by HAS relation. But if any of these AD nodes are connected by an EXCLUDES relation, I should filter that one out.

For example, if I search by B1, I should get AD4,AD2

AD1 has EXCLUDES with D1 and AD3 has excludes with C1, hence filtered out.

I am using the following cypher

```
MATCH path=(p:AD)-[:HAS|EXCLUDES]-()<-[:CHILD_OF*]-(u:User) USING INDEX u:User(id) WHERE u.id = 'B1'
with p,
     collect( filter( r in rels(path) 
                      where type(r) = 'EXCLUDES'
              ) 
     ) as test
          where all( t in test where size(t) = 0 )
return p
```

The issue is when I search with C1, it return AD4,AD3,AD2. How can I eliminate AD3 from the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:CHILD_OF*` doesn't include your starting node. To include that, set a lowerbound of 0:

`[:CHILD_OF*0..]`

That said, there are probably better ways to form your query. Try this, maybe:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.id = 'B1'
WITH u, [(p:AD)-[:EXCLUDES]-()<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(u) | p] as excluded
MATCH (p:AD)-[:HAS]-()<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(u)
WHERE not p in excluded
RETURN p
```

EDIT

The [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) feature was released with Neo4j 3.1. You won't be able to use that in an older version. Try this instead:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.id = 'B1'
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:AD)-[:EXCLUDES]-()<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(u)
WITH u, collect(p) as excluded
MATCH (p:AD)-[:HAS]-()<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(u)
WHERE not p in excluded
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon!!I completely missed the lower bound. But when you say a better way of writing this query, is it based on the performance or any other factor? Could you please clarify?

Comment: See how the timings (after a few executions) stand up between them. Then run a PROFILE on both queries, see how the db hits look between them. From my personal point of view, I tend to lean toward simpler to understand queries. In this case the approach I used was: match and collect the excluded nodes, then match the :HAS nodes that aren't excluded.

Comment: Thanks. I would definitely try it out. I am using an old version of neo4j(2.3.6). The | symbol in your query is throwing error for me. Is it something available in newer versions?

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to use that. Updated my answer accordingly.